# modify jquery cycle plugin to use image titles instead of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle

Following [this excellent tutorial](http://takerootdesign.co.uk/blog/web-design/adding-named-navigation-jquery-cycle-gallery) I'm very close, but he uses the contents of `h2` tag rather than something dynamically created. I want to use the image titles instead. I thought something like this would work, but it's not.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//Create an array of titles
var titles = $('#slideshow img.item').map(function() { 
    return $(this).prop('title'); 
});

    $('#pause').click(function() { $('#slideshow').cycle('pause'); return false });
    $('#play').click(function() { $('#slideshow').cycle('resume'); return false; });

    $('#slideshow').before('<ul id="nav-slide"></ul>').cycle({
        fx: 'fade', 
        speed: 'slow', 
        timeout: 6000, 
        pager: '#nav-slide',
        pagerAnchorBuilder: function (index) {  //Build the pager
            return '<li><a href="#">' + titles[index] + '</a></li>';
        },
        updateActivePagerLink: function(pager, currSlideIndex) {
            $(pager).find('li').removeClass('active').filter('li:eq('+currSlideIndex+')').addClass('active');
        }
    });

});
```

Anyone know how to grab contents of `title` rather than a block/inline element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`title` is not a child but a property of your images

```
var titles = $('#slideshow img.item').map(function() { 
    return $(this).prop('title'); 
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GTZbu/)

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working for the cycle script. I've updated my question to include the whole script in case there's something else funky in it.

Comment: Ah, I see. the `.item` refers to a CSS class. I was thinking it was a javascript call (obviously my JS skills are lacking.) I removed that and it worked splendidly. Thanks!